# SQLite insert or select primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to insert a row if it doesn't already exist. If it does already exist, I want to get it's primary key.
Can this be done without using two queries, for instance using a UNIQUE constraint on the columns and ON CONFLICT ... TELL ME THE CONFLICTING ROWID?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I don't have experience with SQLite.  However, after perusing the online documentation, I don't believe that it supports data-change table references, so no, this isn't possible.

My reccommendation is to write your `INSERT` in such a way that it won't *fail* if the row exists - it just won't insert a row.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO destinationTable (colA, colB) 
            (SELECT :colAValue, :colBValue
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                               FROM destinationTable
                               WHERE uniqueColumn = :uniqueColumn))
```

This works because the selection won't return a row if it already exists.  You can then either look at the return code/state to see if it `INSERT`ed a row, or just `SELECT` with the unique column, to get the identity column.

**DON'T** rely on your constraint to catch this.  Constraints are to catch application errors, and this is solely a business/implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. You can't, with SQLite, either INSERT data or, on some condition, SELECT it.

Other SQL engines might allow it, but SQLite can't.

What you can do is `INSERT OR IGNORE`, which will just not bring up an error. See http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html